# After drop two of the SharePoint SPFx Framework came out on Friday. I get error cannot find module gulp-core-build

Tags: spfx-tooling

After drop two of the SharePoint SPFx Framework came out on Friday. (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-Drop-2) ...
I followed the instructions to upgrade my webpart so:-  When I type gulp nuke I get cannot find module gulp-core-build.

```
    C:\XXX\YYY\ZZZ\Documents\SPFx\Projects\SiteInfo-webpart>gulp nuke
     module.js:327
     throw err;
     ^

     Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-core-build'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
     at Object. (C:\XXX\YYY\ZZZ\Documents\SPFx\Projects\SiteInfo-webpart\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\lib\index.js:13:25)
     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned this in the github issue as well (https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/151).  What version of npm are you running?  Can you make sure it is version 3?

Comment: Hi Pat npm -v = 3.10.7 (also answered in GitHub)  Regards  Nigel